# How can I create my embedded system for raspberry pi zero W?

Tags: raspberry-pi-zero

I want to create my own raspberry pi os how can i do?
I tried to search on the web
*Create Embedded system raspberry pi zero W*
But I find only for raspberry pi 2-3-4

Comment: You're going to need some adaptability. It's unlikely that there's resources on such a niche topic for every single platform. Look through the sources about the other raspberry pie models, and look to see what carries over